# Creating a list of files from a list of directories in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a list of many directories, each of which have 5 files inside, from these files within each directory I want to select one (for example let us say the one with extension .txt) and compile a list of these .txt files....how do I create a loop that selects txt files from a list of directories in R?

Comment: use `lapply` like this: `lapply(dirs,function(x) list.files(x,'.txt$',full.names=TRUE)` where `dirs`is your list of directories

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
dir(path = ".", pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

Where `path` is the root that contains all the folders you want to look up, `pattern` is regular expression that matches the files you are interested in (in the example all the files with the `.txt` extension, `full.names` return the full path of the files, and `recursive`to explore all the subfoders in `path`. This returns a vector with the full path for the files that match your query.

Comment: Thank you sinQueso!

Answer (score 2):

`list.files` is a vectorized function already, so you can pass the vector of directories to it, no loop needed.

```
my_dirs <- c("foo/bar", "foo/baz")
all_text_files <- list.files(my_dirs, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)
```

If you want a list separating files by directory...

```
split(all_text_files, dirname(all_text_files))
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of directory names in `dirs`,
you can get the `.txt` files in all of them as a vector with:

```
files <- unlist(lapply(dirs, function(dir) list.files(path = dir, pattern = '\\.txt$')))
```

You can achieve the same using a loop as you asked,
but it's less elegant, and I don't recommend it:

```
files <- c()
for (dir in dirs) {
  files <- c(files, list.files(path = dir, pattern = '\\.txt$'))
}
```