# Get a data frame of file names in a folder with R

Tags: r, for-loop

Lets say I have a folder called "Muffins" which has a lot of different recipes for muffins (e.g., banana, blueberry, etc.), each in an independent file. I want to get all filenames within the "Muffins" folder.

My expected output is a data.frame of two columns: Column 1 = muffins (the folder name) and Column 2 = the individual file name.

```
      Food     Recipe
      Muffins  Banana
      Muffins  Blueberry
      Muffins  Chocolate
      etc.     etc.
```

I think this can be achieved with a simple for-loop, but I haven't find a way to make it work.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if your provided a reproducible example...I'm not sure I understand the structure of your data...

Comment: The answer here  may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576588/creating-a-list-of-files-from-a-list-of-directories-in-r    list.dirs() and list.files() will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on linux, so you may need to tweak this answer a little bit if you're in Windows:

As @Elin pointed out in the comments, `list.files()` is your friend here. Please read the help file for it. We also will use the `read.table` function in order to split the string returned by `list.files` into the folder and file columns:

```
read.table(text = list.files("folder", 
                             include.dirs= FALSE, 
                             full.names=TRUE), 
           sep = "/")
```

What does the code do:
`read.table` reads a vector and separates columns when it finds the "/".
`list.files` searches `"folder"`, returns `full.names`, that is, file names that follow the folder name, as in a path, and does not `include.dirs`.